# How to enable concurrency in asp.net for searching remote directories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, network-share

I need to search a large number of network shares for a given set of files within an MVC.net application.  Doing so serially works, but is very slow.

I can use `Parallel.ForEach` in a console application and it seems to work well, but Parallel.ForEach does not seem to work in Mvc.Net and async/await is recommended from what I can tell.

```
    static void SearchAll()
    {
        var shares = new[] { @"\\share1\dir1", @"\\share2\dir2", @"\\share3\dir5" };
        var lookfor = new[] { "file.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.jpg", "file4.xml", "file5.zip" };
        var paths = new List<string>();
        var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        foreach(var share in shares)
        {
            var found = Search(share, lookfor);
            paths.AddRange(found);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Found {paths.Count} files in {sw.Elapsed}");
    }

    static List<string> Search(string share, IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        List<string> found = new List<string>();
        foreach(var filename in files)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(share, filename);
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                found.Add(path);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

I hoping to be able to use async/await for searching directories within an MVC.NET Controller Action, but haven't been able to get it to work.  Since there is no `File.ExistsAsync` for `EnumerateFilesAsync`, I'm not sure the best way to wrap those synchronous calls to enable searching multiple directories.  Seems like this problem is suited for async/await due to network/IO bound aspect.

Comment: What are your performance goals? Is it enough to speed the search by a factor of 4, or you need improvement x100 or something?

Comment: Looking for 2-6x improvement.  I see about a 4x improvement in the console app using Parallel.ForEach method.  Hoping for similar with async/await.

Comment: If this operation is not expected to be called frequently, I would say go with the `Parallel.ForEach` approach, setting a sensible value for `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. If it is called frequently, then you should consider other approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since there is no File.ExistsAsync for EnumerateFilesAsync, I'm not sure the best way to wrap those synchronous calls to enable searching multiple directories. Seems like this problem is suited for async/await due to network/IO bound aspect.

Unfortunately, yes. These are I/O-based operations and *should* have asynchronous APIs, but the Win32 API does not support asynchrony for these kinds of directory-ish operations. Curiously, the device driver layer *does* (even for local disks), so all the underlying support is there; we just can't get at it.

`Parallel.ForEach` should work on ASP.NET; it's just not recommended. This is because it will interfere with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics. E.g., if you do a large `Parallel` operation, other incoming requests may have to wait longer to be processed due to thread pool exhaustion. There are some mitigations for this, like setting the min number of thread pool threads to the default plus whatever your `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is (and ensuring there's only one `Parallel` at a time). Or you could go as far to break out the file enumeration into a separate (private) API call so it exists in its own AppDomain on the same server, with its own separate thread pool.

Comment: Thanks.  Removing a nested Parallel.ForEach and limiting MaxDegreeOfParallelism seemed to do the trick.

Btw, I've been reading your book on C# Concurrency!  Learning a lot - thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying frequently, and the network shares are updated infrequently, you could trade memory for speed by keeping an in-memory mirror of all filenames in the network shares, and query this mirror instead of the filesystem. You would need multiple `FileSystemWatcher` objects, one for each network share. Every time a notification arrived a task would be spawn, to enumerate the files of the changed directory. This way you could achieve performance gains of 100x or more.

Here is an implementation:

```
public class RemoteWatcher : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DirectoryData[] _ddArray;
    private readonly Task[] _initializingTasks;

    public RemoteWatcher(string[] shares)
    {
        _ddArray = shares.Select(path =>
        {
            var dd = new DirectoryData();
            dd.Path = path;
            dd.Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
            dd.Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            dd.Watcher.Created += (s, e) => OnChangedAsync(path);
            dd.Watcher.Renamed += (s, e) => OnChangedAsync(path);
            dd.Watcher.Changed += (s, e) => OnChangedAsync(path);
            dd.Watcher.Deleted += (s, e) => OnChangedAsync(path);
            dd.Watcher.Error += (s, e) => OnChangedAsync(path);
            dd.InProgress = true;
            return dd;
        }).ToArray();
        // Start processing all directories in parallel
        _initializingTasks = shares.Select(ProcessDirectoryAsync).ToArray();
    }

    private DirectoryData GetDirectoryData(string path)
    {
        return _ddArray.First(dd => dd.Path == path);
    }

    private async void OnChangedAsync(string path)
    {
        var dd = GetDirectoryData(path);
        Task delayTask;
        lock (dd)
        {
            dd.Cts?.Cancel();
            dd.Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            delayTask = Task.Delay(200, dd.Cts.Token);
        }
        try
        {
            // Workaround for changes firing twice
            await delayTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) // A new change occured
        {
            return; // Let the new event continue
        }
        lock (dd)
        {
            if (dd.InProgress)
            {
                dd.HasChanged = true; // Let it finish and mark for restart
                return;
            }
        }
        // Start processing
        var fireAndForget = ProcessDirectoryAsync(path);
    }

    private Task ProcessDirectoryAsync(string path)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var dd = GetDirectoryData(path);
            var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Select(Path.GetFileName);
            var hash = new HashSet<string>(fileNames, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            lock (dd)
            {
                dd.FileNames = hash; // It is backed by a volatile field
                dd.InProgress = false;
                if (dd.HasChanged)
                {
                    dd.HasChanged = false;
                    var fireAndForget = ProcessDirectoryAsync(path); // Restart
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<string[]> SearchAllAsync(params string[] fileNames)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(_initializingTasks);
        return _ddArray.SelectMany(dd =>
            fileNames.Where(f => dd.FileNames.Contains(f))
            .Select(fileName => Path.Combine(dd.Path, fileName))
        ).ToArray();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var dd in _ddArray) dd.Watcher.Dispose();
    }

    private class DirectoryData
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public FileSystemWatcher Watcher { get; set; }
        public bool HasChanged { get; set; }
        public bool InProgress { get; set; }
        private volatile HashSet<string> _fileNames;
        public HashSet<string> FileNames
        {
            get => _fileNames; set => _fileNames = value;
        }
        public CancellationTokenSource Cts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public static RemoteWatcher RemoteWatcher1 {get; private set;}

// On application start
RemoteWatcher1 = new RemoteWatcher(new[] { @"\\share1\dir1", @"\\share2\dir2", @"\\share3\dir5" });

// Search
var results = RemoteWatcher1.SearchAllAsync(new[] { "file.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.jpg", "file4.xml", "file5.zip" }).Result;

// On application end
RemoteWatcher1.Dispose();
```

First searches will be postponed until all network shares have been processed. Subsequent searches will not be blocked by filesystem changes. Results can be a bit stale because the previous mirrored data are used, until the current processing completes.